# Winning the relay race for your team

Tags: geometry, optimization

Relay race, members of a team of three take turns running from the point P to a point on the circle; To A for the first, B for the second, and C for the third, starting and returning to point P, transferring the baton at point P.

Assuming that all runners have the same rate, your task is to maximize the length of their run for the competitors by selecting the point P.

[image]

Comment: Sure. Now, what is the source of this problem, please? It looks like $A$ and $C$ are diametrically oppposite each other...is this the case? Do we know anything about the relative locations of the points involved? And what does the question have to do with the title?

Comment: I planed to place this in the puzzle section. I will leave it here if interested. A, B, and C may be located any where on the circle. You select the best P for your team, while the other team selects a point for your team. By selecting the maximum length for the opposite team you improve your opportunity to win. BTW, what was the edit?

Comment: "You select the best P for your team, while the other team selects a point for your team." So, both teams are selecting a point for your team? And, again, what is the source of the problem? Where does it come from? If you want to know what the edit was, you just click on the "edited x hours ago" over my name.

Comment: Based on a problem someone had with regard to a triangle, I thought about this problem. You might say I invented it...:)